# How are feed views meant to be used?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts, upstream

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/views?view=azure-devops):

> Feed views enable developers to share a subset of package-versions with their consumers.

Okay, got it. I know how to promote a package to a view but... how exactly am I supposed to "share" the packages from that view through a feed view? I don't see any reference to any view in the instructions to connect to a feed. The only place I've seen where the view of a feed is actually used is in the feed settings when you specify another feed as an upstream source. Is that it? Are views only meant to be used in feeds when they are referenced as upstream sources?

Also, when you are creating a view, you have the options to provide read access to the view to:

- People in all organizations associated with the Azure Active Directory
- People in the current organization
- Specific people

Does this mean that you just can't use as an upstream source a feed that is from an external Azure Devops organization that is not associated with your Azure Active Directory? And if it is true that views are only useful when you configure this feed as an upstream source for another feed, wouldn't it make more sense to remove the "Specific people" and just use Permissions instead?